# Converting the distance in meters using object.distance function from shapely lib

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

This code allows to obtain the **distance** from a data point to each element of my `geojson` (it uses real `coordinates`, the ones used by google maps), and then I can know which is the closest point.

In the image, red point is my input coordinates, and the shape with border red is the nearest point according my logic.
[image]
In this location I am getting this value `0.0002648...` in properties in my `array` of `json` `features[x].properties.distance`. I need convert that value in meters.

I want to make a condition according to the distance meters from the given point.

How can I do the conversion to pass this value to meters?

```
import json

from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping, shape
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

with open("g.geojson") as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

ref_point = Point(-95.29756, 29.85736)

features = []
min_distance = None
min_index = None

for i, feature in enumerate(geojson["features"]):

    # Could be improved with Haversine distance, or distance in UTM coordinates for example
    p1, p2 = nearest_points(shape(feature["geometry"]), ref_point)
    distance = p1.distance(p2)

    if min_distance is None or distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        min_index = i

    feature["properties"] = {"index": i, "distance": distance}
    features.append(feature)
    features.append(
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {"index": f"closest_point_{i}", "distance": distance},
            "geometry": mapping(p1),
        }
    )

features = sorted(features, key=lambda x: x["properties"]["distance"])

features.append(
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"index": "ref_point", "distance": 0},
        "geometry": mapping(ref_point),
    }
)
```